# Convert decimal to string for comparison in U-SQL

Tags: azure, u-sql

I am trying to convert data from a loaded in CSV file to an Azure table, but I'm running into problems where one of the values is loading in a string and the equivalent value in the table is decimal.

```
@ProdOutput = 
    EXTRACT 
    [p_description] string, 
    [p_code] string, 
    [p_price] string, 
    [p_colour] string
FROM "testing/martin/items.csv" 
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);  


// @items has been brought in from a table in Data Lake Analytics
@holdings_query = 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY h.code) AS rn, 
       h.description AS Description, 
       h.cd AS Code,    
       h.priceGBP  AS Price,    
       h.col AS Colour
FROM   @items AS h;



@result = 
    SELECT 
    p_description == Description ? p_description : String.Concat("Mismatch", p_description, " !! ", Description)  AS [Desc], 
    p_code == Code ? p_description : String.Concat("Mismatch", p_code, " !! ", Code)  AS [Code], 
    p_price == Price ? p_price: String.Concat("Mismatch", p_price, " !! ", Price)  AS [Price]
FROM @holdings_query AS h
LEFT OUTER JOIN @prod_data AS p ON h.Code == p.p_code;
```

The problem is I want the EXTRACT statement to bring everything in generically as a string, as I'm not always going to know the type of each of the columns. So when I do the comparison in the final statement, I would like to convert the Price from decimal (as it is in the table) to string to compare with what is coming out of the CSV.

I have tried ToString(), ToString("G"), (string?) but they all throw up errors. what am I doing wrong?

TIA
Martin

Example data:
Items.csv:
"Item1","IT1","3.65"
"Item2","IT2","4.00"
"Item3","IT3","524.2123"

@items table:
"Item1", "IT1", 3.65
"Item2", "IT2", 4.00
"Item3", "IT3", 524.2123

Comment: Can you provide some sample data please?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Decimal.Parse` on the `string` type.  This method "...converts the string representation of a number to its Decimal equivalent".  I got the following statement to work, where `p_price` is the string value:

```
@result =
    SELECT 
            Decimal.Parse(p.p_price) == h.Price ? 1 : 0 AS isEqual
...
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but received the following:   
    Description 
    C# compiler reported that this expression is not valid C#.
    Resolution 
    Make sure that a valid C# expression is specified.
    Details at token 'h', line 237
near the ###:
**************
         ### h.[Price] == Decimal.Parse(p.[p_Price]) ? h.[Price] : String.Concat("Mismatch", h.[Price], " !! ", p.[p_Price])  AS [Price] 
Error 
E_CSC_USER_INVALIDCSHARP
Message 
C# error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'decimal?' and 'string'

Comment: Also, the problem with this is I would need to know when the value is decimal to convert it. So, is there a way of saying IF TYPE IS DECIMAL then do decimal conversion and comparison, else do string comparison?

Comment: Keep it simple and try and get the expression I gave you.  The conditional operator must return the same data type so i think that's why you are getting that error.  The [GetTypeCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621341.aspx#GetTypeCode) returns the typeCode for a string so should be able to do what you need.

Comment: You could also use TryParse. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621309.aspx for examples.